# Adding a custom JavaScript code to functions.php file in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I am trying to add a JavaScript code to `functions.php` file using `wp_head` hook. The JavaScript code just adds a DataLayer to the top of Google Tag Manager Container in `<head>` tag, on the Thank you page.

I have attempted to use the following code:

```
function addDataLayerToHead(){
  if (is_checkout() && !empty( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) )  {
     wp_enqueue_script('Custom-JS', 'https://xxxxxx/dataLayer.js', array('jquery'), '', 
     false);
  }  
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'addDataLayerToHead', 10 );
```

When I run my website, the product page will not be available it says error in function "**addDataLayerToHead**".

Any help?

Comment: Are you putting PHP code in a javascript function? That isn't going to work.

Comment: I am hooking Javascript in php code (function.php file for WordPress).